# Telerik Reporting - Subreport - reportsource

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, telerik-reporting

I have been working with reports for the past one month or so. I am presently working with subreports.
Say I have a telerik reporting file (report_1) which has a subreport element in it. In the same project as report_1 is, I have couple of other telerik reporting files. Cant I refer these reporting files as report source of the subreport in report_1?
If yes, I am not able to see them in the dropdown of the reportsource property.
If no, why?
Or is there anything that I am missing? or, is there anything that I need to do to get the reporting files on to the dropdown.
I have seen your previous postings, which said about re-building the project. But, I am  not building the project through visual studio. So, please suggest what can be done.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help you with this one but may I suggest to ask your question on Telerik forum as their staff answer most questions within 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the other reporting files you want to use as subreports in the same project, you should be able to select them from the report source property. May be you are missing a reference. In any case it might be useful to check the documentation on creating [Master-Detail reports](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/designing-reports-master-detail.html)  and the section about subreports on the [Telerik reporting learning guide](http://www.telerik.com/documents/TelerikReporting-LearningGuide.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not told us what you're using to build the report, how can we answer?

Well, if you were actually using VS the answers would be
Answer to Q1: yes
Answer to Q2: there could be various reasons (these are the ones I have seen):

1. the sub-report is in a different namespace that is not referenced
2. your sub-report has an error and is not compilable
3. the report does not have a unique name

Perhaps if he shares with us what build tool he is using, we may be able to help better.

Comment: @DomenicDatti **TLDR**? The down-vote is completely unfair. Please read further than simply _the_ _subject_. The 2nd last sentence in the OP's comment _clearly_ _says_ "I am **not BUILDing** the project through visual studio" ... so obviously, I am simply asking what then, is he using to **BUILD** the project file which contains the Telerik report since there are multiple other ways to build. (S.O. tip: Before criticizing others about not considering what is _"clearly"_ stated ... perhaps you should read what it "clearly says". Otherwise you just come off looking silly )

Comment: Just fyi, I did read the full question, but it's not the most well written.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ReportSource.ReportDocument.DataSource property for binding.

e.g. ReportSource.ReportDocument.DataSource/=Fields.Items

Answer (score 0):

make sure the subreports have their report headers stripped out.

then, if you look at the properties of the subreport element on the main report and go to reportsource (as suggested by Camilo)
there is an ellipsis button (...) 
- click that then select ***object*** source.

your subreports should then be in the drop down